# Automorphismgroups of Graphs, Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking on an Algorithm, to find the Automorphisms Groups of Graphs. Example, I have a Picture of a Graph how do I find the Automorphism Group of it? I have checked a few books I have on Graph Theory, but they do no cover it. There must a be a book, or a list of examples? I have added the Graphs I had. I have no clue how to solve this. Is there a book on this topic? An Algorithm would be great to solve this by hand! No coding :)

[image: img]

Comment: Find the spectrum of eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix for each graph. If these spectra are different then the graphs will not be automorphic.

Comment: I just want to let you know that it will be much easier to find the automorphism groups by hand for small graphs than to implement some algorithm.

Comment: Are there not, somewhere in the text, some examples of graphs and their automorphism groups? It is almost certain that you're not being asked to follow any general mechanical procedure for computing automorphism groups. Instead you're supposed to _use intuition and ad-hoc reasoning_, to familiarize yourself with (a) how group automorphisms behave on simple examples such as these, (b) how to recognize simple groups once you have figured out what the possible automorphisms in each case are.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit What are "automorphic" graphs? Do you mean isomorphic?

Comment: I agree with Henning Makholm but to answer your question, you can look [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism). See also the list of references, in particular the [paper by McKay](http://cs.anu.edu.au/people/bdm/nauty/pgi.pdf).

Comment: My Prof is always saying, if he doesnt bother explaining, if you dont get it now, sleep over it.!

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Here is a way to find $\text{aut}(G)$, here we assume $G$ is not labeled (as in the picture you provide).

1. Begin by labeling the vertices of $G$ with elements from $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$, let us call this labeling $L$.
2. Among all possible labelings of $G$ find those that result in the same graph as the one the one labeled at 1. It is important to note that labeling $L$ itself is one way of doing this. Say the resulting set of labellings obtained here is $\mathcal{L}=\{L_1,L_2,\ldots,L_k\}$.
3. For each labeling $L_i \in\mathcal{L}$ we will write how $L_i$ is obtained from $L$ by permuting the labels of $L$ (this will be a bijection). Note that since $L\in\mathcal{L},$ then not permuting any label yields the same graph, this corresponds to the identity permutation. There might be more elements in $\mathcal{L}$. In other words, in this step we are looking for the set of permutations of $L$ that give us an element of $\mathcal{L}$. The resulting set of permutations is $\text{aut}(G)$.

---

Now a couple of examples.

a) Suppose $G$ is $K_n$. It is easy to see that in this case $\mathcal{L}$ results in all possible labelings of $G$. Going through step 3 will yield all $n!$ permutations, that is $\text{aut}(G)=S_n$.

b) Suppose now that $G$ is the graph shown below to the left. Let us assume that labeling $L$ from step 1 is the one displayed on below to the right.
[image: A tree and a labeling of the tree.]

We are now left to find all labelings of $G$ that result in the same graph as the one on the right. Note that the labels of vertices in $\{1,2,3\}$ can be freely swapped. Similarly vertices in $\{8,9\}$ can be freely swapped. It is not too hard to see that these are the only vertices whose labels can be exchanged. If all details are carried out you should obtain the following permutations as a result:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 8
\end{array}\right).$$

The set of permutations above gives the automorphism group of $G$.

Comment: A simple improvement would be to try to permute only nodes with the same degree.

Comment: @Idéophage: correct. At this point one may add many more simple heuristics. Vertices in $k$-cycles should only be permuted with vertices in $k$-cycles. Another option is to also look at the degrees of neighbors of the vertex in question. Or even distance to a vertex of a given degree.

Comment: Can we say that "find those that result in the same graph as the one labeled at 1" is the same as saying, "that results in the exact same adjacency matrix"?

Comment: Yes, that can be said. In fact, if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$, then the automorphism group of G is represented by the set of permutation matrices $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}AP$.